# Active menu image will not display on individual pages when using php includes although hover does work

Tags: php, javascript, include, dreamweaver, server-side-includes

My main navigation menu is in a sidebar on the left side of the page. The menu uses two different images for each link (a regular image and an image that is used as both the hover image and the active image.

I've saved the menu it as its own php page (sidebar.php) and have it in every page as an include.

Everything works perfectly except that the active image doesn't display for each page as it used to when the pages were all individual html pages. The weird thing is that the hover image works just fine but on each php page the same image should stay displayed for the active image but doesn't.

I'm using javascript to change the images in the menu.

Here is the sidebar.php with the menu:

```
<ul class="nav_main">
  <li><a href="index.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','home','images/home_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','home','images/home_hover.png','images/home_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home Page" name="home" border="0" id="home" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','about','images/about_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','about','images/about_hover.png','images/about_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/about.png" alt="About Us" name="about" width="254" height="43" border="0" id="about" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="services.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','services','images/services_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','services','images/services_hover.png','images/services_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/services.png" alt="Our Services" name="services" width="254" height="43" border="0" id="services"  /></a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','portfolio','images/portfolio_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','portfolio','images/portfolio_hover.png','images/portfolio_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio" name="portfolio" width="254" height="43" border="0" id="portfolio" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','contact','images/contact_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','contact','images/contact_hover.png','images/contact_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="Contact Us" name="contact" width="254" height="43" border="0" id="contact" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="resources.php" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','resources','images/resources_hover.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','resources','images/resources_hover.png','images/resources_hover.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="images/resources.png" alt="Resources" name="resources" width="254" height="43" border="0" id="resources"  /></a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for this ul:

```
ul.nav_main {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.nav_main li {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here is the header.php file that contains the javascript that is controlling the menu images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>Title goes here</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Description Here" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="various keywords yada yada" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css"> 
      #main_content, #sidebar { zoom: 1;} 
    </style> 
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
      var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
      var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
      if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
    }

    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
      var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
      d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
      if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
      for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
      if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
    }

function MM_nbGroup(event, grpName) { //v6.0
  var i,img,nbArr,args=MM_nbGroup.arguments;
  if (event == "init" && args.length > 2) {
    if ((img = MM_findObj(args[2])) != null && !img.MM_init) {
      img.MM_init = true; img.MM_up = args[3]; img.MM_dn = img.src;
      if ((nbArr = document[grpName]) == null) nbArr = document[grpName] = new Array();
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
      for (i=4; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
        if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
        img.src = img.MM_dn = args[i+1];
        nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    } }
  } else if (event == "over") {
    document.MM_nbOver = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=1; i < args.length-1; i+=3) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = (img.MM_dn && args[i+2]) ? args[i+2] : ((args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up);
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    }
  } else if (event == "out" ) {
    for (i=0; i < document.MM_nbOver.length; i++) {
      img = document.MM_nbOver[i]; img.src = (img.MM_dn) ? img.MM_dn : img.MM_up; }
  } else if (event == "down") {
    nbArr = document[grpName];
    if (nbArr)
      for (i=0; i < nbArr.length; i++) { img=nbArr[i]; img.src = img.MM_up; img.MM_dn = 0; }
    document[grpName] = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=2; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = img.MM_dn = (args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up;
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
  } }
}
function MM_effectAppearFade(targetElement, duration, from, to, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoFade(targetElement, {duration: duration, from: from, to: to, toggle: toggle});
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="QCG0iVdbmkKMlncL_4ZfRnrR86PHEbplI5dVZhXVY8o" />
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/home_hover.png','images/about_hover.png','images/services_hover.png','images/portfolio_hover.png','images/contact_hover.png','images/resources_hover.png','images/web_icon_fade.png','images/logos_icon_fade.png','images/photo_icon_fade.png','images/cards_icon_fade.png','images/home.png')">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/header_logo.png" width="960" height="250" alt="Todd Day Graphics Logo" border="0" /></a></div>
```

Even though I'm new to using includes I feel like I'm missing something very simple in why the active images won't display in the actual pages (index.php, about.php, etc).

Comment: Wow. Haven't seen those ugly old Dreamweaver image hover scripts in a while... You really should look at using basic CSS for your hover effects and your life will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks Mike and believe it or not I actually had a feeling that was coming. I haven't used anything like this in ages. I created this site some time ago and I think it is the only site I did that used images for menu links. Not fond of those anymore.

Comment: Also check out using CSS sprites. No need to have a bunch of little images floating around when you can use one single images as the background for all of this.  That being said, I don't see in your sidebar script where you are doing anything different based on the current page you are on. In most cases for something like this there would be some PHP check against `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine which page you are on and start with the "active" image in this case, thought I honestly can't remember if there is something in the javascript to do that for you.

Comment: I wonder if the best bet would be to just scrap that script all together and reformat that menu using css classes for the different menu items??

Comment: That really depends on how much work you want/need to put into it. My guess is the active link would not have any hover condition at all, you all you would need to do in PHP is check against the REQUEST URI and output a different anchor tag (with hover image and no javascript events) for the link that matches the current page.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That seems reasonable to me!